# I can't add to a value when i use parameter, but it works fine when not in the function

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So when i try to *+= 1* in the function, the value doesent update, But i can update the value without paramter just fine.

Please help.

```
public void buystock(int amountofstocks, int stockvalue)
{
    int stocksbuy = 400;
    if (amountofstocks >= 40)
    {
        if (GetComponent<Money>().MoneyValue >= (stockvalue + stocksbuy))
        {
            GetComponent<Money>().MoneyValue -= stockvalue + 400;
            amountofstocks += 1;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (GetComponent<Money>().MoneyValue >= (stockvalue + 10))
        {
            GetComponent<Money>().MoneyValue -= stockvalue + 10;
        }
    }
}
```

and my other one which is:

```
public void buyoil1()
{
    buystock(oil1amountofstocks, oil1value);
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `int` is value type, so it's **value** is copied into function parameter and any modification on that parameter is local.

Comment: Its supposed to be:         if (GetComponent<Money>().MoneyValue >= (stockvalue + 10))
        {
            GetComponent<Money>().MoneyValue -= stockvalue + 10;
        }

Comment: Ahh! But how do i fix it?

Comment: What @tchelidze ment is: whatever you do in the function, stays in the function. it is not reflected outside of it

Comment: @tchelidze value type has nothing to do with the issue. `int` is immutable so you can’t change it to begin with. The reason is that the parameter is *passed by value* so assigning a new value to it will have no effect whatsoever outside the method. The same thing would happen with a reference type.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Its amazing how many answers here are simply wrong. They all go on about `int` being a value type and that bit of information is completely irrelevant here.

`int` is an *immutable* type, you can’t mutate it which would be the only reason why value types could be relevant in the context of this question.

Somehow the answers seem to be mixing up `amountofstocks =+ 1` with mutating a value type which is simply false! The only thing that is going on here is that the variable `amountofstock` is being *assigned a new value* and because the parameter is passed by value (default behavior in c#) the assignment has no effect whatsoever back at the call site (the assignment is made on a *copy*).

*The exact same thing would happen if `amountofstock` were a reference type*. If `amountofstring` were to be a `string` there would be no change at all in the behavior of your code.

To make a long story short, the behavior you are seeing is due to the fact  that  parameters in c# are, by default, passed by value, period. It has nothing to do, in this particular case, with `amountofstock` being a value type.

If you need to reassign the value of a parameter and have it persist back at the call site then you need to pass it by reference; in your case `ref amountofstock` although in some scenarios `out` is more appropriate.

Comment: @Everts first sentence of your answer:it is the case of reference against value type. That’s completely misleading and wrong.

Comment: "Its amazing how many answers here are simply wrong" - he _is_ passing a struct which _is_ copying the value rather than passing a reference _to_ the variable? Not sure which part was wrong...

Comment: @everts `int` is immutable. Can you change `1`?

Comment: @ScottPerham The beginning is wrong. He first stated this is due to the parameter being a valid type. That fact is irrelevant here.

Comment: @everts exactly, and where exactly do Value types become relevant?

Comment: @InBetween "The beginning is wrong... that _fact_ is irrelevant here" - So just to confirm, you are happy that an int is a struct? :P (I'm done now)

Answer (score 2):

`Int` is **value** type, so it's value is **copied** (opposite to it's reference) into function parameter and any modification on that parameter is **local**.

In order to pass **reference** of `int`, you should use **ref** keyword.

Try following

```
public void buystock(ref int amountofstocks,ref int stockvalue)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a struct to your method which is copying the value rather than passing a reference to the variable.

Consider using a return value, `out` or `ref` to achieve the desired result.

Here is the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/passing-parameters) on passing arguments to methods in C# which helps explain the problem